# Select users who send a post with a break from 5 minutes in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, select

is it possible to select every user who send two or more post inside a minimum timeframe from 5 min, from the first to the last post. In this example user 1 should not shown up, he sends 4 posts put from 17:05 to 17:08 = only 3 Min. User 2 should show on the select but user 3 not, he has only one post.

I can use tsrange but i dont not know how i can create a query with tsrange(first_post_time,last_post_time) > 5 Min

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now());

CREATE TABLE posts(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    post_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES (1,'Smith');
INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES (2,'Maria');
INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES (3,'Bill');

INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (1,'2014-01-05 17:05');
INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (1,'2014-01-05 17:06');
INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (1,'2014-01-05 17:07');
INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (1,'2014-01-05 17:08');
INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (2,'2014-01-05 18:05');
INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (2,'2014-01-05 19:05');
INSERT INTO posts (user_id,post_time) VALUES (3,'2014-01-05 20:00');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first_post_time is the minimum post time and last_post_time is the maximum post time and you need the count of posts. That's just aggregates.

```
select id
from posts
group by id
having count(*) > 1
   and max(post_time) - min(post_time) > interval '5 minutes'
;
```